# wget inside chroot - cannot verify certificate?

Tags: wget, chroot, certificates

I'm trying to install some packages into a chroot and when getting the key I get these errors:

> root@devpc:/# wget -O-
>   'https://ceph.com/git/?p=ceph.git;a=blob_plain;f=keys/release.asc'
>
> --2014-05-13 22:59:18--  https://ceph.com/git/?p=ceph.git;a=blob_plain;f=keys/release.asc
>   Resolving ceph.com (ceph.com)... 208.113.241.137,
>   2607:f298:4:147::b05:fe2a Connecting to ceph.com
>   (ceph.com)|208.113.241.137|:443... connected. ERROR: cannot verify
>   ceph.com's certificate, issued by '/C=GB/ST=Greater
>   Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA 2':
>   Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority. To connect to
>   ceph.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

I've tried copying the /etc/ssl folder across but that didn't resolve it.
Neither did installing ssl-cert.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found the answer after much poking around and searching.

> apt-get install ca-certificates

Probably

> apt-get install ssl-cert

is needed too if you haven't already installed it.